# Change application direction using Phonegap or SAPUI5

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, sapui5

I am not able to change my app direction using (html dir="ltr"), after android device language has been changed to arabic. How can I change my app direction to ltr using phonegap or sapui5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change application direction, sapui5 provides script tag attributes for configuration. Just include sap-ui-rtl="false" and sap-ui-language="ar" attributes in your script something like,

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core-all.js" data-sap-ui-rtl="false" data-sap-ui-language="ar"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is kind of not possible,

**Reason :** Because if you do that then you would need to build entire android app again and then run it in device.

**Possible Solution**

You can use `navigator.language` to detect device language and based on that you can load different `CSS` and `HTML`.

Comment: Reference [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization)